# Accessing nested data in a supposed dict

Tags: python, aws-lambda, slack-api

Alright, I'm stumped. I have googled everything I can think of from nested Dicts, Dicts inside Lists inside Dicts, to JSON referencing and have no idea how to get to this data.

I have this AWS Lambda handler that is reading Slack events and simply reversing someone's message and then spitting it out back to Slack. However, the bot can respond to itself (creating an infinite loop). I thought I had this solved, however, that was for the legacy stuff. I am Python stupid, so how do reference this data?

Data (slack_body_dict print from below):

```
{'token': 'NgapUeqidaGeTf4ONWkUQQiP', 'team_id': 'T7BD9RY57', 'api_app_id': 'A01LZHA7R9U', 'event': {'client_msg_id': '383aeac2-a436-4bad-8e19-7fa68facf916', 'type': 'message', 'text': 'rip', 'user': 'U7D1RQ9MM', 'ts': '1612727797.024200', 'team': 'T7BD9RY57', 'blocks': [{'type': 'rich_text', 'block_id': 'gA7K', 'elements': [{'type': 'rich_text_section', 'elements': [{'type': 'text', 'text': 'rip'}]}]}], 'channel': 'D01MK0JSNDP', 'event_ts': '1612727797.024200', 'channel_type': 'im'}, 'type': 'event_callback', 'event_id': 'Ev01MN8LJ117', 'event_time': 1612727797, 'authorizations': [{'enterprise_id': None, 'team_id': 'T7BD9RY57', 'user_id': 'U01MW6UK55W', 'is_bot': True, 'is_enterprise_install': False}], 'is_ext_shared_channel': False, 'event_context': '1-message-T7BD9RY57-D01MK0JSNDP'}
```

There is an 'is_bot' there under 'authorizations' I want to check. I assume this will let the bot stop responding to itself. However, for the life of me, I cannot reference it. It seems to be nested in there.

I have tried the following:
def lambda_handler(api_event, api_context):

```
    print(f"Received event:\n{api_event}\nWith context:\n{api_context}")
    
    # Grab relevant information form the api_event
    slack_body_raw = api_event.get('body')
    slack_body_dict = json.loads(slack_body_raw)
    request_headers = api_event["headers"]
    
    print(f"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!body_dict:\n{slack_body_dict}")
    print(f"#######################is_bot:\n{slack_body_dict('is_bot')}")
    print(f"#######################is_bot:\n{slack_body_dict("is_bot")}")
    print(f"#######################is_bot:\n{slack_body_dict(['is_bot']}")
    print(f"#######################is_bot:\n{slack_body_dict(["is_bot"]}")
    print(f"#######################is_bot:\n{slack_body_dict['authorizations']['is_bot']}")
```

As you can see I have absolutely no clue how to get to that variable to tell if it is true or false. Every 'is_bot' print reference results in an error. Can someone tell me how to reference that variable or give me something to google? Appreciate it. Code is below in case it is relevant.

```
import json
import os
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError

def is_challenge(slack_event_body: dict) -> bool:
    """Is the event a challenge from slack? If yes return the correct response to slack
    Args:
        slack_event_body (dict): The slack event JSON
    Returns:
        returns True if it is a slack challenge event returns False otherwise
    """
    if "challenge" in slack_event_body:
        LOGGER.info(f"Challenge Data: {slack_event_body['challenge']}")
        return True
    return False

def lambda_handler(api_event, api_context):
    
    # Grab relevant information form the api_event
    slack_body_raw = api_event.get('body')
    slack_body_dict = json.loads(slack_body_raw)
    request_headers = api_event["headers"]
    
    # This is to appease the slack challenge gods
    if is_challenge(slack_body_dict):
        challenge_response_body = {
            "challenge": slack_body_dict["challenge"]
        }
        return helpers.form_response(200, challenge_response_body)
        
    # This parses the slack body dict to get the event JSON
    slack_event_dict = slack_body_dict["event"]
    
    # Build the slack client.
    slack_client = WebClient(token=os.environ['BOT_TOKEN'])

    # We need to discriminate between events generated by 
    # the users, which we want to process and handle, 
    # and those generated by the bot.
    if slack_body_dict['is_bot']: #THIS IS GIVING ME THE ERROR. I WANT TO CHECK IF BOT HERE.
        logging.warning("Ignore bot event")
    else:
        # Get the text of the message the user sent to the bot,
        # and reverse it.
        text = slack_event_dict["text"]
        reversed_text = text[::-1]

        # Get the ID of the channel where the message was posted.
        channel_id = slack_event_dict["channel"]
        
        try:
            response = slack_client.chat_postMessage(
                channel=channel_id,
                text=reversed_text
            )
        except SlackApiError as e:
            # You will get a SlackApiError if "ok" is False
            assert e.response["error"]    # str like 'invalid_auth', 'channel_not_found'
```

Comment: `slack_body_dict['authorizations'][0]['is_bot']` or `any(auth['is_bot'] for auth in slack_body_dict['authorizations'])`

Comment: Could you explain why that works? Is it a list inside for a dict?

Comment: It's a dict inside a list inside a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the data is:

```
{
    "authorizations": [
        {
            "is_bot": true
        }
    ]
}
```

So you would need to first index `"authorizations"`, then to get the first item `0`, and lastly `"is_bot"`.

```py
data["authorizations"][0]["is_bot"]
```

Alternativly, you could iterate over all the authorizations and check if any (or all) of them are marked as a bot like so:

```py
any(auth["is_bot"] for auth in slack_body_dict["authorizations"])
```